# How can I add sitemaps.xml to a website running on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, sitemap

I have a website on Windows Azure with two web instances.

Is it possible to create a sitemaps.xml file that:

- Gets added or replaced even if the web instance fails (or is overwritten)
- Auto-updates itself

Comment: please refine your question. sitemap.xml is usually a "Static file". Are you refering the ASP.NET SiteMap.xml, or are you refering the google's indexed sitemap.xml file? For ASP.NET site map, you can digg the Internet for articles on how to create dynamic sitemap provider. If you refers google's sitemap.xml, you can create your own IHttpHandler, map it to the path "sitemap.xml" and generate the content on the fly. That way your sitemap.xml will always be up-to-date, and will be fault-tollerant.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Azure, instances of the same role are identical. The same sitemaps.xml are replicated on both instances. If one instance is down, the other instance will continue to serve requests without any issues(although performance will reduce if there’re a lot of requests). In this case, we don’t need to update sitemaps.xml. To a client, it only sees the load balancer. It doesn’t care about instances.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.